Python app update - Drop in Google rankings
My Python programmer fixed a bug/issue in the app regarding file input names. The website runs as fast as ever, with no change in performance (100% score on PageSpeed ​​for computers). The app works even better now, but there has been a major drop in Google rankings, and I'm losing positions for keywords.
Do you have any idea what could be causing this problem? The strange thing is that I am not dropping in position for 1x app on a specific subpage that was fixed, but overall on the entire website, where I only have simple HTML/JavaScript apps.
It’s been a few days, and there is no improvement in Google rankings, so I think this is not something temporary.

It sounds like the drop in rankings could be related to the recent changes, even if performance seems fine. Sometimes, even small adjustments can affect how Google views your site. It might be worth checking if any key elements (like metadata, structured data, or internal linking) were unintentionally altered during the fix. Also, consider if the changes impacted how Google crawls or indexes your site. If everything seems correct, it might be a good idea to monitor the situation and see if rankings stabilize, or consider reaching out to an SEO specialist for a deeper look.

If the content itself hasn't changed, then I suspect it's most likely down to the ongoing core update. Google are likely to be going after anything that looks low quality and machine generated at the moment because of the problems caused by AI spam.  This is likely to hit some sites unfairly.  Did this drop happen after 15th August?
Template code rarely makes a difference to ranking unless it impacts speed, ability to crawl, or semantic markup.
It might be worth giving an example of a page & keyword which is suffering both before (Wayback Machine) and after the change so that people can take a deeper look, as you haven't given enough information to rule out any other issues.

yes, you are right after 15th August. So I know now that the code change wasn't the culprit. Thank you.
Btw. I wasn't using Ai content for this website.
I would have one more question for you. Imagine that there is no relevant content for a keyword. Can a website with AI-generated content rank well if it has no competition?

As always with SEO, only Google really know.  I'd assume if anything has good enough positive signals (backlinks etc), it will rank.  If all the signals are negative it will not, and AI is going to be a negative signal.  This is worth a read for the current known state-of-play with SEO https://searchengineland.com/how-google-search-ranking-works-445141
